# XPath set a default value when a div is empty

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

I have this html to parse:

```
<parentA>
  <div class="child"> 25 </div>
</parentA>

<parentB>
  <div class="child"></div>
</parentB>
```

I'm using lxml, and with

```
//div[@class="child"]/text()
```

I only get [25], but I would like to get the second div, too, like [25, null]

Is there a way to get the empty div?

Comment: You could use XPath to get the two divs, and then extract the text later, no?

Comment: how do i get only the divs?

Comment: Are you not familiar with XPath? Even just looking at that query, it should be possible to figure it out, no?

Comment: i tried with just //div[@class="child"] but i get an <Element div at 0x407fbe0> how do i extract text from that?

Answer (score 1):

Try with below code:

```
from lxml import html

html_code = '''<parentA>
                    <div class="child">25</div>
               </parentA>
               <parentB>
                   <div class="child"></div>
               </parentB>'''


dom = html.fromstring(html_code)
div_text = dom.xpath('//div[@class="child"]')
for i in div_text:
    print(i.text)
```

Output:

`25
None`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
nothing = """your html above"
doc = lxml.html.fromstring(nothing)
[t.text for t in doc.xpath('//div[@class="child"]') ]
```

Output:

```
[' 25 ', None]
```